# Encrypted Alert21- Error code 214

Tags: tls, gcm

I am working on TLS 1.2 Cipher `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`, After send the application data server throws an error message `Encryption alert (21)`.

I have mentioned the parameter shard by the server given below.

```
Decryption key: ab98fbfabe869b008697b9f62b8f59ee7a3165db6a0fdc37e2bac41d73995889
nonce: f53672195e441268b2fedf5d       (hex)
adata: 00000000000000011503030002     (hex)
cipher text: 7a6d                     (hex)
tag: 30518e9ba5daee98827555c680c87499 (hex)
decrypted data: 0214                  (hex)
```

After the GCM decryption we got the data `0124`. But the `0214` is not [a valid SSL alert message](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/developer-for-zos/9.1.1?topic=trace-ssl-alert-messages).

[image]

Please give me the support for find what type of error found here.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? Please rather update your question instead of creating a new one, or at least remove the former. You should definitely also take more time formatting your post.

Comment: [02 14 is level=fatal description=bad_record_mac](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2) And note even where decryption is separate from MACverify, which it isn't with GCM, TLS1.2 and 1.3 use 20/0x14for _both_ MAC and decryption errors and no longer use 21/0x15 at all. And a _protocol_ like TLS isn't itself cryptography, so security.SX would be more suitable.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085 and Maarteen for your reply and I will rectify my mistakes on upcoming days.

Comment: This is my encrypted WS packet.  0000000000 000001 **<nonce>** fd041f5ecd2ab17dd4a90dca6f abbdd5980080f4de4d9213d47a7c670e 5fa771d920d04e46377d258812deca12 b76562609b46b0328f4af1d65df6c321 629266979a1c0c1cd974d10191689b7d 4350aa00eb2df03f6bb5af0064efa830 03e808f7a63f82da8cb87d25dab982e6 701f23d5820188583c74157711aad587 68930680418688514f9f4326c602fd77 88025c00fe79ab581f8a7352182433d4 bc120476cbff7563d6e358235e5ddfd0 2c1111344f7d64a678c9  **<enc msg>** f392af81a2604276013c8b2dc7925d01 **<tag>** Using this encrypted packet and It's MAC. I am able to get my original data.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 what is security.SX?

Comment: security.stackexchange.com (versus crypto.stackexchange.com). It's a pain to keep writing out stackexchange.com over and over so I abbreviate it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you.